# find max value in a data.frame by group and show its date as year-month-day

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Here my dataframe:

```
df = read.csv(text = '"Date","Value","ID","WY"
                  1975-02-01,-1.16543693088,"Tweed",1975
                  1975-03-01,-1.05372283483,"Tweed",1975
                  1975-04-01,-1.06632370439,"Tweed",1975
                  1975-05-01,-1.18903485356,"Tweed",1975
                1992-05-01,-1.04737467143,"Ouse",1992
                1992-06-01,-1.4058281451,"Ouse",1992
                1992-07-01,-1.13608647243,"Ouse",1992
                1992-08-01,-0.802566581309,"Ouse",1992
                1992-09-01,-0.551433852821,"Ouse",1992
                1992-10-01,-0.625997598552,"Ouse",1993
                1992-11-01,-0.483559758609,"Ouse",1993
                1992-12-01,-0.792013395632,"Ouse",1993
                1993-01-01,-0.754618121962,"Ouse",1993
                1993-02-01,-1.2504282139,"Ouse",1993
                1996-01-01,-0.945410385985,"Trent",1996
                1996-02-01,-0.84249575782,"Trent",1996
                1996-03-01,-1.10332425045,"Trent",1996
                1996-04-01,-1.22634133042,"Trent",1996
                1996-05-01,-1.2335181635,"Trent",1996
                1996-06-01,-1.23451130358,"Trent",1996
                1996-07-01,-1.25902677738,"Trent",1996
                1996-08-01,-1.13068733413,"Trent",1996', header = TRUE)
```

I need to find the annual maximum value for each ID and WY group.

The following code do the trick very easily but its output only shows the year of each annual maximum whereas I am interested also in the relative month and day:

```
df_AMAX = aggregate(df$Value, by = list(df$WY, df$ID), max)
colnames(df_AMAX) = c('Date', 'ID', 'Value')
print(df_AMAX)

 Date    ID      Value
1 1992  Ouse -0.5514339
2 1993  Ouse -0.4835598
3 1996 Trent -0.8424958
4 1975 Tweed -1.0537228
```

My output should be:

```
 Date           ID      Value
1 1992-09-01  Ouse -0.5514339
2 1993-11-01  Ouse -0.4835598
3 1996-02-01  Trent -0.8424958
4 1975-03-01  Tweed -1.0537228
```

It should be a silly thing but please let me know if you have any suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(Value)] , .(ID, WY)]`

Comment: that's great @akrun. please post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subset` with `ave`.  Note that the function passed to `ave` returns a logical but `ave` will coerce it to the class of `Value` so we use !! to make it logical again.  No packages are used.

```
mx_all <- function(x) if (length(x)) x == max(x)
subset(df, !!ave(Value, ID, WY, FUN = mx_all))
```

or

```
mx_first <- function(x) if (length(x)) seq_along(x) == which.max(x)
subset(df, !!ave(Value, ID, WY, FUN = mx_first))
```

These give the same answer for the sample input and will always give the same answer if there is a unique maximum in each group but if there are multiple maxima in a group then the first one gives all of them and the second gives the first.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course a `dplyr` solution, too:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(WY, ID) %>% 
    summarise(
      Value = max(Value),
      Date = Date[which.max(Value)]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
   select(ID:Date)
```